# Fixing incompatibility between amsbook and glossaries-extra

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra, amsbook

I am trying to add a glossary to a document written with the `amsbook` class using `gls2bib` and `glossaries-extra`. Unfortunately, there seems to be a weird interaction between `glossaries-extra` and the table of contents in `amsbook`. I suspect that it has something to do with `glossaries-extra` attempting to rewrite the custom `\markleft` command defined by `amsbook` (see §5.1 of the glossaries-extra.sty v1.45 manual and §2.26 of the amsclass v2.20.6 manual).

Indeed, the following MWE compiles using `amsart` but not using `amsbook`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{glossary.bib}
@entry{a,
  name={my entry},
  symbol={\ensuremath{a}},
}
\end{filecontents}
% \documentclass{amsart}  % works
\documentclass{amsbook}   % does not work
\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={glossary}]
\begin{document}
% Compiles with amsbook if the following
% line is commented out:
\tableofcontents

\section{introduction}
\gls{a} is a glossary entry.


\printunsrtglossary
\end{document}
```

Here is the error produced by `pdflatex glossary && bib2gls glossary && pdflatex glossary` with the `amsbook` line uncommented:

```
(./glossary.aux) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
\@glsxtrnotinmark
(./glossary.toc) [1{/home/rak/.texlive2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pd
ftex.map}]
! Argument of \glsxtrifinmark has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.22 \end
         {document}
?
```

Adding `\glsxtrRevertMarks` right before `\begin{document}` gets the MWE to compile with amsbook, but the glossary then has two entries in the table of contents.

Comment: I had a similar problem with the glossary showing up twice in the TOC when using `amsart`. Adding importing `glossaries-extra` with `toc = false` removed exactly one of them (I don't know what's going on tho...:/).